# Como devo nomear variáveis na linguagem SQL?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, variáveis, tabela-banco-de-dados

Existe algum padrão de **nomeação de variáveis** em SQL?
Quero definir o mais padronizado possível,para os seguintes casos:

- Nomeação do banco de dados
- Nomeação das tabelas
- Nomeação das colunas
- Nomeação das CONSTRAINS

Existe algum ANSI que informe isso?

Comment: Nunca ouvi falar de algum tipo de norma ISO ou ANSI sobre tal tipo de padrão de nomenclatura. Sempre vi tal padrão como uma coisa interna a cada organização.

Comment: Encontrei um style guide para auxiliar sobre estas questões de padrão:
https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/business-ops/data-team/sql-style-guide/

Comment: Na minha opinião, a dica é: Se começou com um padrão, termine com ele. Geralmente, vários frameworks tem padrões de nomeação, mas cada um usa de uma forma. Por isso o mais importante é definir uma regra pra não ficar bagunçado e não sair inventando moda no meio do caminho.